# why calendar module is not working on python 3?

Tags: python, calendar

I'm typing this code :

```
import calendar

cal = calendar.month(2014, 7)
print(cal)
```

I don't know whats the problem is or where i got spelling mistakes.
It just keeps giving me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'month'
```

Comment: Does this work for you in Python2?

Comment: @kirelagin: it works *just fine* in Python 3. Provided you are not masking the library, that is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure it does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In all likelihood you have a *local* file `calendar.py` that is imported instead of the module in the standard library.

Find out where by printing the module:

```
import calendar
print(calendar)
```

Rename that file, it is masking the standard library version.