# Python - Date and Time: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'month'

Tags: python, date

This is my calendar code in Python and I have saved it to my folder as `calendar.py`.

```
import calendar
a = calendar.month(2016, 3)
print (a)
print ("The Calendar :")
```

When I execute it, it raises an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calendar.py", line 1, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/py/calendar.py", line 2, in <module>
    a = calendar.month(2016, 3)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'month'
```

What's going on?

Comment: filename is same as calendar module. rename the file and try again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040033/why-calendar-module-is-not-working-on-python-3

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you used the name calendar.py for your file. Use any other name, and you will be able to import the python module calendar.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply, i have changed my file name but no reflection same error.

Comment: Thank you so much... Fixed successfully. I have removed my .pyc file and again renamed my file. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Do not name the file as calendar.py and there should be no calendar.py file on the same path

Answer (score 1):

You might have given your file name as calendar.py. This is imported instead of the module in the standard library.

Solution:
Rename the file. Also, make sure to delete "calendar.pyc" file located in the same path where you are running the script.

As a check, do the following to locate your module
import calendar
print(calendar)

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the file is not going to be enough, when you import the file a `.pyc` is created so even if you rename you are still going to have a `.pyc` with the same name in the folder so you are still going to be importing from that.

Also if you have any `calendar.py` or `.pyc` in your path before the standard libs `calendar` you will end up importing that also so make sure there are no other files named `calendar.py/pyc` anywhere in your path.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same challenge. If the issue is not with a similar file name, please note that the `prevmonth` and `nextmonth` functions have been deprecated https://bugs.python.org/issue35406

You can still access them using the _prevmonth and _nextmonth functions, but note that they don't check if the month is valid (kindly refer to the link posted above for details), so you may need to write your assert statement before using them

```
MONTH_NUMBER = 12 # enter your month number here
assert MONTH_NUMBER in range(0,13)

# continue the rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the same error but a different result.

I do not have any files nor did i have any files called calendar.py but i did have a method called calendar.

I got around this by adjusting my import

```
import calendar as cal
some_var = cal.monthcalendar(this_year, month))
```

This worked for me. Hope it helps other folks.

Answer (score 0):

If your filename is calendar.py then change the file name after that you won't face any attribute error