# Calendar Module in Python not working

Tags: python, calendar

I tried to use the python calendar module in version 3.5.2 with:

```
import calendar

yy = 2016
mm = 12

# To ask month and year from the user
# yy = int(input("Enter year: "))
# mm = int(input("Enter month: "))

display=calendar.calendar(yy,mm)

# display the calendar
print(display)
```

but every time I try to run it, crashes and says:

```
line 2, in <module>
import calendar

line 4, in <module>
cal = calendar.month(2016, 2)

AttributeError: module 'calendar' has no attribute 'month'
```

Conversely, I tried this in terminal (using Python 2.7), and it does what it is told...!

Just unsure why this doesn't work in one of the latest version of Python

Comment: silly question, but how are you exactly calling it, and with what python version? It works perfectly here (Ubuntu, python 3.5.2), and so it should, according to this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040033/why-calendar-module-is-not-working-on-python-3). You probably calling another file called calendar. Use this to find where that file is: `print(calendar)` Hope this helps! 
EDIT: also according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar), I think that you are looking for the function `monthdatescalendar(year, month)` not `calendar.month()`. please read over the [python**3** documentation for calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.Calendar). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You already named a file calendar.py that it is referencing instead of the calendar module.

https://intellipaat.com/community/65020/why-calendar-module-is-not-working-on-python-3

Comment: What is this contributing in addition to the existing answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366788/7733418